# Is there a high-level DynamoDB module for Node.js that supports secondary indexes?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I see quite a few DynamoDB modules on npmjs.org.  I am guessing that all of them pre-date the introduction of secondary indexes and so don't support them.  Does anyone know of a high-level DynamoDB module for Node.js that supports secondary indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the modules I've written, [dynamo-table](https://github.com/mhart/dynamo-table), supports secondary indexes.

You can specify them in your table constructor and then the library can determine if indexes are required in a query:

```
table = dynamoTable('customers', {
  key: ['id', 'name'],
  indexes: {emailIx: 'email'}
})

table.query({id: 'a', email: {'>': 'b'}}, function(err, items) {
  // query will have been called with IndexName: emailIx
})
```

A `createTable` call will also create the table with the given secondary indexes - and you can specify projections, and types as well.

```
table = dynamoTable('customers', {
  key: ['id', 'name'],
  keyTypes: {age: 'N'},
  indexes: {ageIx: {key: 'age', projection: ['address', 'dob']}}
})

table.createTable(function(err) {
  // will correctly populate LocalSecondaryIndexes and AttributeDefinitions
})
```

Documentation is a bit light on the ground at the moment (typical!), but you should be able to find out more from [the tests](https://github.com/mhart/dynamo-table/blob/master/test/fast.js#L1079-L1321).

Answer (score 1):

The [AWS SDK for Node.js](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornodejs/) supports secondary indices for Amazon DynamoDB. You can find the code for it on [github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) or you can get it through npm:

```
npm install aws-sdk
```

Comment: Well, of course their own SDK supports all of their API features.  I am using it for a lot of things.  But I have found it to be fairly low-level, and I know there are a number of Node modules designed to make it easier to work with DynamoDB, just looking for one that supported secondary indexes.  Found one in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

If you like a MongoDB like interface you can use:
https://github.com/aaaristo/dyngodb

```
npm install -g dyngodb
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently started using [vogels](https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels). It's great - seems well maintained enough and has mongoose-like syntax. It supports secondary indexes and parallel scans, which very few (no?) other dynamo sdk's do. I don't know why I didn't find it in the first 100 searches I did for dynamo+node libraries...